# problem with inner join in many-to-many relationships with entity framework core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5, .net-5

I want to launch a query crossing two tables that are related from many to many and in entity framework core 5, it is not necessary to create the c# class of the intermediate table. So with include I launch the query with left join which is correct, but I need to launch an inner join and I can't because I don't have the c# class of the intermediate table. How would it be possible to do this without having to create the c# class of the intermediate table?

thank you very much

Comment: You'll have to use the virtual collections inside each of the one side entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need intermediate entity in order to achieve inner join in a LINQ to Entities query. All you need is `SelectMany` without `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

For instance, using the sample model from [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) section of the documentation:

```cs
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

the following will generate inner join:

```cs
var query = from post in db.Posts
            from tag in post.Tags
            select new { post, tag };
```

or with method syntax

```cs
var query = db.Posts
    .SelectMany(post => post.Tags, (post, tag) => new { post, tag });
```

Comment: thank you very much, actually doing the table crossing this way: 

`from post in db.Posts
from tag in post.Tags` 

I already force the launch of an inner join which is what I really need, I hadn't thought of doing the crossover like this.